# Не работает скрипт в Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Сделал скрипт, который фиксирует footer, но в Firefox работать не хочет.
Может кто подскажет что нужно изменить, чтобы скрипт работал кросс-браузерно.

```
$(window).bind("load", function(event) {

var footerHeight = 0,
    footerTop = 0,
    $footer = $("#footer");

positionFooter();

function positionFooter() {

    footerHeight = $footer.height();
    footerTop = ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-footerHeight)+"px";

    if ( ($(document.body).height()+footerHeight) < $(window).height()) {
        $footer.css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: footerTop
        })
    } else {
        $footer.css({
            position: "static"
        })
    }

}

$(window)
    .scroll(positionFooter)
    .resize(positionFooter)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Вызывай функцию после её объявления.

```
$(window).bind("load", function(event) {

var footerHeight = 0,
    footerTop = 0,
    $footer = $("#footer");

function positionFooter() {

    footerHeight = $footer.height();
    footerTop = ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-footerHeight)+"px";

    if ( ($(document.body).height()+footerHeight) < $(window).height()) {
        $footer.css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: footerTop
        })
    } else {
        $footer.css({
            position: "static"
        })
    }

}

positionFooter();

$(window)
    .scroll(positionFooter)
    .resize(positionFooter)
});
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает. При ресайзе в Firefox footer не опускается вниз. Например, если установить изначально разрешение 1280*600, а потом поменять на разрешение  1024*960